# Why does using the `Checked` property causes strange error the event can only occur on right hand of += or -=?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on c# on a WPF application.I have written the following code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        RadioButton daw;
        InitializeComponent();

        if (qoneone.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct");

        }
    }
```

A error occurs that says

> event `qoneone.Checked` can only appear on left hand side of `+=` or `-=`

Comment: Apparently `qoneone.Checked` is an event, what are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Why does this question have 2 upvotes ._.

Comment: set condition to if (qoneone.IsChecked.Value)

Comment: @Christo this is a confusing error message if you thought you were accessing a property and instead intellisense led you to pick an event. So I think its a useful question.

Comment: @DaveInCaz I don't find it all that confusing tbh, it says you can have Checked only if you have += or -=.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are accessing the wrong member of `qoneone`.

Instead you have to check the boolean property `qoneone.IsChecked == true`.

`IsChecked` is a property that you can read or write to get or change the current state of the `RadioButton`.

But *`Checked` is an event*. (You could attach an handler to it using `+=` so you can do something when the `RadioButton` state change. Hence the error message.)

Comment: This is likely correct. Can you also clarify to the asker what his code currently does? That way it might be clearer what caused his issue.

Comment: I added a short explanation, hope it can helps.

Comment: also, '== true' is a bad ppractice that hurts code readability.

Comment: @Behrooz not if [`IsChecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) is `Nullable<bool>`

Comment: @dkozl, huh, more bad design:|, the right way to avoid the confusion that I just had is to use GetValueOrDefault w/ a default

Answer (score 0):

As giangregorio has stated, `quone.checked` is a property and this requires an event.

What you should be doing here is a delegate:

```
QueoneChanged += quoneevent;

quoneevent (Object sender, routed event s)
{
  \\insert code here

}
```

Comment: I don't think accessing the event was intentional; the code seems to indicate the OP wanted the boolean property and used the event by mistake.